# Namespaced Dependency Properties in WPF

Tags: wpf, namespaces

How can i create dependency property like:

```
Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled
Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled
```

I am creating Custom Window, with TitleBar... and all i want is to separate TitleBar Width,Height,Margin,Background etc. in namespace like:

```
TitleBar.Width
TitleBar.Height
...
```

Instead of creating TitleBarWidthProperty, and access it like TitleBarWidth="value"

No missunderstandings TitleBar is not control in  my window, it does not exist as a whole thing, its just content part of the window, and all i want is to create namespace separated DPs from which TitleBar components will bind from for example:

```
<Window Background="Blue"
        TitleBar.Background="Red"
>
</Window>
```

---

@Mike Strobel I think this proves that the thing you are talking about is wrong...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency Properties with these type-qualified names are known as *attached dependency properties*.  They can be created in a similar manner as regular dependency properties, with the following differences:

1. The DependencyProperty field should be initialized by calling `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached()`, as opposed to simply `Register()`.
2. Because the property values are "attached" to objects which likely have no knowledge of the property, one usually does not create CLR property wrappers.  Instead, one creates a pair of static Get/Set methods:

   ```
   public static double GetWidth(DependencyObject target) { /* ... */ }
   public static void SetWidth(DependencyObject target, double value) { /* ... */ }
   ```

As an interesting aside, the XAML parser can utilize attached properties that are *not* dependency properties.  Only the relevant static Get/Set methods are required.

While some of the most common use cases in core WPF are to declare properties to be assigned on child elements, e.g., an element arranged by a `Panel`, this is not the only use case.  The idea is that a property declared by an arbitrary type can be used to set a value on any object, even if it has no knowledge of that property.  This makes them useful for [Attached Behaviors](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF), among other things.

In your case, it appears you want to declare new layout-related properties that could be referenced in a Style or Template.  That is also a common use case.  Example:

```
public static class TitleBar {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty WidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Width",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(TitleBar),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(double.NaN));

    public static double GetWidth(DependencyObject target) {
        return (double)target.GetValue(TitleBarProperty);
    }

    public static void SetWidth(DependencyObject target, double value) {
        target.SetValue(TitleBarProperty, value);
    }

    // TODO: Add similar members for additional properties...
}
```

If you want to encourage the property to be set only on `Window` elements, simply replace the first parameter of the Get/Set methods with a `Window` instead of a `DependencyObject`.

Where the property should be declared depends on the use case.  If a property is only meaningful to a specific UI Element (e.g., `Grid` declares `Row` and `Column` as layout hints), then that element should declare the property.  If it is additional metadata to be referenced in Styles or Templates, you should probably declare it in an appropriately named static class (as in my example above).  If it is to be used as part of an attached behavior, it should be declared within that behavior's class.

The name of the class declaring the property is the name that appears to the left of the `.` in XAML references.  In the `TitleBar` example above, the `Width` property would be referenced in XAML as `ns:TitleBar.Width`, where `ns` is mapped to the CLR namespace containing the `TitleBar` class.

Comment: As i understood the reading of attached property and as i see in practice, it attachs Dependency Property on child elements, and i want to just separate Dependency Property name... fix me if i am wrong

Comment: The property will be set on whichever element the property setter is attached to in the XAML. The idea is not necessarily that the value will be set on _child_ elements, but that it can be set on elements that have no knowledge of the property, as it is declared by another type (e.g., Grid defines Row and Column properties that can be set on any element).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are alluding to in your edit.  `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` can be set on any element.  It is meant to be set on an _ancestor_ of a `Grid` element, but that is certainly not a requirement of attached properties in general.

Comment: Hmm where should i put that Dependency Property than, if i create it?
How i will get the TitleBar prefix, anyways?

Answer (score 0):

That's an [attached dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  They can be defined in any type *on* any type.

Here's my snippet I use to create attached dependency properties.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>SnippetFile1</Title>
      <Author>Will Sullivan</Author>
      <Description>Attached Property</Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>AP</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>AttachedPropertyName</ID>
          <ToolTip>The name of the property</ToolTip>
          <Default>PropertyName</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>PropertyType</ID>
          <ToolTip>The Property Type</ToolTip>
          <Default>object</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>ClassName</ID>
          <ToolTip>The name of the containing class</ToolTip>
          <Default>object</Default>
          <Function>ClassName()</Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>TargetType</ID>
          <ToolTip>The type on which the DependencyProperty is attached</ToolTip>
          <Default>DependencyObject</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[#region $AttachedPropertyName$ Attached DependencyProperty
        /// <summary>
        /// An Attached <see cref="DependencyProperty"/> of type <see cref="$PropertyType$"/> defined on <see cref="$TargetType$">$TargetType$ instances</see>.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty $AttachedPropertyName$Property = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
          $AttachedPropertyName$PropertyName,
          typeof($PropertyType$),
          typeof($ClassName$),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default($PropertyType$), On$AttachedPropertyName$Changed)
        );

        /// <summary>
        /// The name of the <see cref="$AttachedPropertyName$Property"/> Attached <see cref="DependencyProperty"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public const string $AttachedPropertyName$PropertyName = "$AttachedPropertyName$";

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the value of the <see cref="$AttachedPropertyName$Property"/> on the given <paramref name="element"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="element">The <see cref="$TargetType$">target element</see>.</param>
        public static void Set$AttachedPropertyName$($TargetType$ element, $PropertyType$ value)
        {
            element.SetValue($AttachedPropertyName$Property, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value of the <see cref="$AttachedPropertyName$Property"/> as set on the given <paramref name="element"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="element">The <see cref="$TargetType$">target element</see>.</param>
        /// <returns><see cref="$PropertyType$"/></returns>
        public static $PropertyType$ Get$AttachedPropertyName$($TargetType$ element)
        {
            return ($PropertyType$)element.GetValue($AttachedPropertyName$Property);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when <see cref="$AttachedPropertyName$Property"/> changes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">The <see cref="DependencyObject">event source</see>.</param>
        /// <param name="e"><see cref="DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs">event arguments</see></param>
        private static void On$AttachedPropertyName$Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            $end$
        }
        #endregion]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Comment: As i understood the reading of attached property and as i see in practice, it attachs Dependency Property on child elements, and i want to just separate Dependency Property name...

Comment: @JovanMeshkov: It's a dependency property on a type that is not defined on the type itself.  If you want a dotted DP name, this is how you have to accomplish it.  Period.